# Сортировка в алфавитном порядке на JAVA+sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

Есть код.
Как его видоизменить, чтобы данные из sqlite выводились в алфавитном порядке от А до Я?

```js
    // Отрядные дела
    public List<DictionaryModel> getListOtryadnieDela(String wordSearch){
        DictionaryModel dictionaryModel=null;
        List<DictionaryModel> dictionaryModelList=new ArrayList<>();
        openDatabase();
        String[] args={"%"+wordSearch+"%"};

        Cursor cursor=mDatabase.rawQuery("Select * From od Where title Like ?",args);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            dictionaryModel=new DictionaryModel(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2));
            dictionaryModelList.add(dictionaryModel);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return dictionaryModelList;
    }
```

Comment: `select * from od where title like ? order by title`

Comment: Подучить самые основы SQL и конструкцию `order by`